# Plugin option for input box validation

Tags: plugins, admin-menu, validation, options, input

I'm crating a plugin option page from the code below. However, it does not explain how to get validation on the input fields.
How do I get validation on `id_number` for NUMBER ONLY?

https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages#Example_.232

Also, can I add default value to the input? on

`<input type="text" id="title" name="my_option_name[title]" value="%s" />'`

So first time install plugin, it will say something instead of nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set the input's `type` to number for numeric validation. 
And use the input's `value` to set a default value.

```
<input type="number" id="title" name="my_option_name[title]" value=123 />
```

If you just want a hint displayed to the user inside the input, use `placeholder`.

```
 <input type="number" id="title" name="my_option_name[title]" placeholder="Phone Number" />
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! Can't believe I couldn't think of that lol